# Google Chrome is zoomed in

Tags: google-chrome

So I was using Chrome and IE together when all of a sudden Chrome decides to change its zoom level not only for the webpage, but the entire browser. I'm not sure if it happened when I restarted Chrome or if it happened when I decided to bring it to the front. So basically, all menu items, logos, icons, absolutely everything appears to have been zoomed in slightly. I have restored to original settings, disabled extensions (I don't use any extensions anyways), uninstalled and reinstalled, and nothing.

I've used the DPI settings in the properties of the Chrome application and nothing changes it. I've changed scaling in Windows and nothing helps.

Everything is larger in Chrome now and it's driving me crazy. Many menu items won't appear fully because of this. Note that this isn't just at the webpage level but at the entire browser level. I've included some images so you can compare. If you look at the youtube homepage, you'll see that everything is larger in Chrome than it is in Internet Explorer.

Scratch that apparently I need reputation in order to post pictures, ugh. If I can get 10 rep soon I'll post some pics.

I'm sorry if my description is rather vague but this isn't something I could search up. No other programs (including IE) are having this issue. THanks very much in advance if anyone can help. This is just driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `Ctrl + 0` obviously does not work. This is an issue with the program as the entire program looks zoomed in. Everything, not just the webpage.

Found a "quick fix" solution from post #38 [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395425):

> 1. Right click on the Chrome link on your desktop
> 2. Choose Properties and then add " /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1" to the existing Link to your path to chrome.exe.

Hope this works permanently. What a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

If you're experiencing a "zoomed in" browser it's because you have an updated version of Chrome. Chrome and FireFox now adjusts the page zoom level according to your Windows settings to better support high DPI displays. For example, if Windows is set to 125% font size (120dpi), the content area will be zoomed by 25%. This is usually the default setting on your computer.

[image]

This means that your updated Chrome and/or FireFox browser will automatically set websites to 125%, and all other browsers remain at 100%.

[image]

**What are possible solutions?**
As of this writing, their isn't a known method of fixing this from a web coding standpoint, due to that it's created from the inner workings of the browser. That being said, their are still some things you can do from the "users" side to fix this:

1. The quickest way around this is to open up your browser and press on your keyboard "ctrl -" (control minus) twice. This will set your website content to 75%, which would be equivalent to 100% in all other browsers (but this will just fix the website content).
2. You can set your computers font-size settings in your control panel to "100%". This will make all of your computer fonts smaller.

I'm sure their is a better answer to this, but for now these are the 2 options that I'm seeing. In FireFox version 22 they also added this feature (as mentioned above), you can see the work around for FireFox here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/962979

I'm sure a similar solution also exist with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your windows default zoom to 100% in display settings and make everything almost unreadable, or (a better way)

You can add a start parameter to your chrome shortcut:

```
"your-chrome-dir\chrome.exe" /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1
```

I know, it's too late, but just in case someone else has this problem...