# Internet Explorer displaying webpages much larger than Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

I've noticed on several of my websites that I.E. by default seems to display all the page content *much* larger than Chrome (seems way more "zoomed in" by default). The site winds up looking like it's to help people with terrible vision problems. Is there a piece of code I could use on my sites on page load to automatically increase the zoom out if people are using I.E.?

Comment: you should give more details about the web page you build

Comment: Maybe because "Chrome and FireFox now adjusts the page zoom level according to your Windows settings to better support high DPI displays" - Source: [Google Chrome is zoomed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525742/google-chrome-is-zoomed-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like this:

[How to Increase browser zoom level on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441557/how-to-increase-browser-zoom-level-on-page-load)

However, controlling the zoom level from code is not a good idea due to scalability issue.

Answer (score 0):

The default zoom level of the Internet Explorer depends on the dpi setting of your system.

Other users will default to 100% but on my system IE defaults to 120%.